# Display form error message without reloading the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

In a Rails 6.1 application I've moved the new action from a separate page to a modal and now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to display only the error message (in case it's present, like "name can't be blank") directly in the form instead of reloading the whole page.
Because even in this case I would not know how to reload the form directly and display the error message.

```
  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)

    if @list.save
      redirect_to list_path(@list)
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

This is the form present in the modal created with simple_form

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@list) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>
          <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
          <div class="form-inputs my-3">
            <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

The alternative solution would be to use flashes, but I would be more happy if the error message was displayed directly in the form without reloading the whole page.

If it helps, this is [my project](https://watch-list-app-demo.herokuapp.com/) at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) gem combined with [client_side_validations-simple_form](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form), since you're using `simple_form`. It achieves just what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. I tried to implement it but somehow it does not work. Maybe is something related to the configuration. What I did not understand from the documentation is, to which path should I redirect if @list.save is false?

Comment: There's no need to change the controller config if it's false, because when there's errors, the plugin will display the error below the field (just like simple_form, but without reloading the page). Is there any errors from javascript in the console?

Comment: No error message is displayed in the console. The only behaviour I get is that once I try to save an unnamed list, the button changes the value from "Save" (assigned by me) to "Create List".
I've created a pull request for this branch, if you'd like to take a look at it [PR](https://github.com/d-tello/rails-watch-list/pull/2)

Comment: I couldn't run your project locally because I got all types of errors from bundle, I'm using rails 5  but taking a close look at your code, I could see there's only 2 details you may have missed: the order of the gems in your `Gemfile`, the docs mention the order matters, so you need to put in this **exact** order: simple_form > client_side_validations > client_side_validations-simple_form. You put simple_form last, this may be causing the problem. Also, I think you don't need the code in the `client_side_validations` initializer, you can comment everything

Comment: I thought the order was for installation. I have an extension in vs code that formats the text when it is saved and that is why the gems are sorted alphabetically. Anyway I have tried changing the order in the Gemfile as mentioned in the documentation and also commenting out the config file but unfortunately no change.